# how to store date from datepicker to sqlite?

Tags: android, date, sqlite, android-sqlite

My code is:

```
 taskDB.insertDate(selectedDate,selectedId);
```

SQlite DB:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME+ "(" +KEY_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +KEY_TASKNAME+ " TEXT, " +KEY_STATUS+ " INTEGER," +KEY_FAV+ " INTEGER," +KEY_DATE+ " TEXT"+")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
```

Insert query:

```
public void insertDate(String date, int id){
    String sql = "UPDATE task SET date = "+date+" WHERE id = " +id;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d(TAG,"id is:" +id+ ", date is: "+date);// log is below
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Log:

```
05-26 10:23:14.538 15298-15298/? D/TaskDB: id is:2, date is: 17-05-2017
```

In log of insert query i get the correct date that i selected from the `datepicker` but in the table it is in different format.[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64OJn.png) is the screenshot of `sqlite` table after insertion of date

Comment: try to set sqlite datatype Date

Comment: put single quotes around date to represent string like , `"UPDATE task SET date = '"+date+"' WHERE id = " +id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query like this and try again

`String sql = "UPDATE task SET date = '"+date+"' WHERE id = " +id;`

I have changed placed the date in single quotes , whenever you are adding a string value into a query , you need to place them in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194002/how-to-store-date-from-datepicker-to-sqlite/44194140#comment75401538_44194002) , you need to put single quotes around `date` to represent string, like

```
"UPDATE task SET date = '"+date+"' WHERE id = " +id;
//                      ^        ^
```

From [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes
>   ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two
>   single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the
>   backslash character are not supported because they are not standard
>   SQL.